# Excel data table analysis

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large data array.  In each line there are zeros and then some codes such as "H3" and "505" Some are letters, some are numbers and some are a combination of both.  What I want to do is have a column that picks up the first thing in each row that it finds that is not zero and puts it into the column (the data in each row is the same as the other cells in that row, they don't vary). I think I should do it with a form of =INDEX but can't get it to work. 
An example of the rows is below:

```
0     0    H3    H3    0
0    505  505    0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=INDEX(A1:E1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A1:E1<>0,),0))
```

The inner INDEX `INDEX(A1:E1<>0,)` returns an array of TRUE/FALSE and the MATCH returns the relative location of the first `TRUE` to the outer INDEX.

[image]

Comment: @ianl please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.